# Does $f_n(x)=e^{\frac{-x}{n}}$ converge uniformly to $1$ on $[0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

Given $f_n:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with
$$f_n(x)=e^{\frac{-x}{n}}, $$ 
it's easy to see that this sequence converges pointwise to $f(x)=1$.

However I am sure that if convergence is uniform also. How can I approach that?

Comment: @Jack What was wrong with your answer?

Comment: @SahibaArora: My reasoning was wrong.  Uniform convergence implies $\lim_n\int_{[0,\infty)}f_n=\int_{[0,\infty)}f$. But in this case, one can also interchange the limit and the integral.

Comment: @Jack Thank you for explaining that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence $(f_n)_n$ is not uniformly convergent in $[0,+\infty)$ because
$$\sup_{x\geq 0}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\geq 0}|e^{-x/n}-1|=\sup_{t\geq 0}(1-e^{-t})=1\not \to 0$$
where we set $t=x/n$. However, $(f_n)_n$ is uniformly convergent in $[0,a]$ in $a\geq 0$:
$$\sup_{x\in [0,a]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in [0,a]}|e^{-x/n}-1|=\sup_{t\in [0,a/n]}(1-e^{-t})=1-e^{-a/n}\to 0$$
as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima  Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n (x)-1|\ge$$

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}|f_n (n)-1|=1-\frac {1}{e}\ne 0$$

thus the convergence is not uniform at R.

Answer (score 1):

If the convergence were uniform, there would be an index $N$ with the property that $n \ge N$ implies $|e^{-x/n} - 1| < \frac 12$ for *all* $x \in [0,\infty)$. This is turn would lead to $e^{-x/N} > \frac 12$ for *all* $x \in [0,\infty)$.  This will lead to difficulty for sufficiently large $x$.